# Need richfaces drag-drop example

Tags: jsf, drag-and-drop, richfaces

i am in need of example of drag and drop component in richfaces.In their website they offer the sample without backing bean(java class).So i need the detailed example of drag-drop component.Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the source code here: http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/richfaces/tags/3.3.3.Final/samples/